# Create log file with custom name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

How to create log file with custom file name in **cakephp 2.5.1**.

I am written following code

```
$this->log("Data : ".print_r($this->data,true),'debug');
```

It create's `debug.log` file in `tmp/log` folder but when I write custom name like

```
$this->log("Data : ".print_r($this->data,true),'data');
```

This code do not create any log file. My Question is how to create log file with custom name?

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as for the other question: [Start reading the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#writing-to-logs). A huge part of the profession is to *read* documentation.

> Changed in version 2.5.
>
> CakeLog does not auto-configure itself anymore. As a result log files
>   will not be auto-created anymore if no stream is listening. Make sure
>   you got at least one default stream set up, if you want to listen to
>   all types and levels. Usually, you can just set the core FileLog class
>   to output into app/tmp/logs/: